# Select rolling totals by month more data

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I have been using to track users sales. Previously they ere required to make a quota each month. Now, however they would like to change the rule to allow them to start any month, so they may go from June                to June or whatever. they also want users to start over immediately if they miss a month. This does seem to be a more equitable system because if they didn't make the quota in March, for example, they were unable to count any they made after that month for the entire year. This really messes up my query though, and I don't know how to fix it. anyone have a solution?

here is the existing t-sql.

```
    @Year int
    AS
    BEGIN


    DECLARE @DateStart datetime
    DECLARE @DateStop datetime

    SELECT @DateStart = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT( char(4), @Year) + '-01-        01')
    SELECT @DateStop = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT( char(4), @Year + 1) + '-01-        01')
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT r.riderid,
    r.dname, 
    DATEPART(yyyy, m.ridedate),
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 1 THEN m.quota     ELSE            0  END) AS [jan],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 2 THEN m.quota ELSE 0               END) AS [feb],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 3 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [mar],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 4 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [apr],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 5 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [may],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 6 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [jun],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 7 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [jul],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 8 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [aug],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 9 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [sep],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 10 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [oct],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 11 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [nov],  
    SUM(CASE DATEPART(mm, m.datesale) WHEN 12 THEN m.quota ELSE 0 END) AS [dec],
    SUM(m.quota) as [tot] 

FROM users u 
    JOIN mysales m 
    ON m.riderid = u.riderid
Where m.datesale Between @DateStart AND @DateStop
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, m.datesale), u.userid

ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, m.datesale), SUM(m.quota) DESC


END
```

OK -here is data
The table holds the users id, the customer id , amount of sale and date of sale
The query pulls the user,  the sum of sales by month. User 250 made quota in July/2016, but did not in August, so he should get an entry in #quota for July, and September, but because he did not in August he has to restart in September; user# 300 has made quota from Jan 2016 to SEPT  so he has qualified for his bonus as long as he finishes the 12 months. User 350 has successfully finished the year and should   get a bonus. at this time in prod there is no quota table, would that simplify? What I need is a list of users that are in the running.

```
--drop table #sales
--drop table #quota
create table #sales
(
    --saleid int    --PK
    userid int -- salesperson FK
,   customerid int --FK
,   sale_amt decimal
,   date_sale datetime
)


insert into #sales values
(300,1301,542.90,'3-2-2016'),                                                                                   
(300,1301,782.70,'3-4-2016'),
(300,1541,600.70,'3-7-2016'),
(300,903,640.71,'3-10-2016'),
(300,1745,900.01,'3-29-2016'),
(300,1440,2040.71,'2-10-2016'),
(300,903,640.71,'2-20-2016'),
(300,414,1489.00,'1-18-2016'),
(300,1645,1322.00,'1-20-2016'),
(300,1200,1156.09,'4-2-2016'),
(300,1204,1456.00,'4-20-2016'),
(250,1140,156.89,'4-12-2016'),
(250,1240,1176.69,'4-14-2016'),
(250,840,480.61,'4-17-2016'),
(250,1940,500.71,'5-17-2016'),
(250,1425,4800.61,'6-1-2016'),

(250,1840,701.32,'6-15-2016'),
(250,1840,701.32,'7-15-2016'),
(250,1840, 2701.32,'8-15-2016'),
(450,8421,2500.61,'7-17-2015'),
(450,8422,2500.1,'8-17-2015'),
(450,843,2500.1,'9-17-2015'),
(450,8431,2500.00,'10-17-2015'),
(450,1431,2500.00,'11-17-2015'),
(450,4311,2500.00,'12-17-2015'),
(450,4310,2500.00,'1-17-2016'),
(450,1310,2500.00,'2-17-2016'),
(450,1310,2500.00,'3-17-2016'),
(450,130,2500.00,'4-17-2016'),
(450,1130,2500.00,'5-17-2016'),
(450,113,2500.00,'6-17-2016')

Select userid
, sum(sale_amt)      Sale
, DATEPART(mm,date_sale) as[month]
from #sales
group by userid, DATEPART(mm,date_sale) order by userid

create table #quota
( 
    qid int --PK
,   userid int -- salesperson FK
,   quota bit -- awarded when sales => $2500.00
,   datesale datetime -- date quota made
)
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? Doesn't "in the running" mean that they met the quota *last month*. That's an easy query.

Answer (score 0):

Just one possible way to write a query that looks back `@running_months` number of months to verify that no quotas have been missed during the window for each user:

```
select userid from users u
where not exists (
    select 1 from #sales s
    where s.userid = u.userid
        and date_sale > dateadd(month, -@running_months - 1, current_timestamp)
        and datediff(month, sales_date, current_timestamp) between 1 and @running_months
    group by month(sales_amt)
    having sum(sales_amt) < 2500
)
```

**EDIT:** I later realized that you probably do have users with no sales during a month so you'll probably need to actually verify the condition that all the months are over quota rather than none of the months are under quota:

```
select userid from users u
where userid in (
    select userid from
    (
        select userid from #sales s
        where s.userid = u.userid
            and date_sale > dateadd(month, -@running_months - 1, current_timestamp)
            and datediff(month, sales_date, current_timestamp) between 1 and @running_months
        group by month(sales_amt)
        having sum(sales_amt) >= 2500
    ) q
    group by userid
    having count(*) = @running_months
)
```